# Vue open a component in a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In App.vue I have a button to open a component . Inside the component BigForm, I also have a button to open a component named, . But as I open the  component. Vue re-render the page with the warning:

```
The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.
```

App.Vue

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="showModal()">Show</button>
    <BigForm v-if="modal" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import BigForm from "./components/BigForm";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    BigForm,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      modal: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showModal() {
      this.modal = !this.modal;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

BigForm.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <form style="height: 300px; width: 300px; background-color: green">
      <button @click="showSmallForm()">Show small form</button>
      <SmallForm
        v-if="toggleSmallForm"
        style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: yellow"
      />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import SmallForm from "./SmallForm";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    SmallForm,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      toggleSmallForm: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showSmallForm() {
      this.toggleSmallForm = !this.toggleSmallForm;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And SmallForm.vue:

```
<template>
  <form>
    <input placeholder="Small form input" />
    <button>This is small form</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

This is the code to my example in codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/late-cdn-ssu7f?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to Vue itself but the HTML.

When you use `<button>` inside `<form>`, the default `type` of the button is `submit` ([check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form#the_htmlelementbutton_element)) - when you click the button, the form is submitted to the server causing the page to reload.

You can prevent that by explicitly setting type `<button type="button">` (HTML way) or by preventing default action (Vue way) `<button @click.prevent="showSmallForm()">Show small form</button>` (see [event modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers))

Also note that using `<form>` in another `<form>` is [not allowed in HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

Comment: thank you, it's work now. What if smallform is not a child component of bigform but they're both child component of App.vue and I want to have a button in BigComponent that shows the SmallForm ?

Comment: click handler in BigForm must [emit event](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) which `App.vue` will handle and toggle the SmallForm...